# Recall a previous sent push-notification on iOS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

For a notification-app I need to recall messages previously sent via APNS in case those messages are outdated or read on another device - even if the app is not running.

As there is no "remove"-call via `APN` and also apps are not launched on `remote notifications`, I assume that the only possible way is to use `PushKit` and `Voice over IP` background mode.
Since we don't use VOIP, the app might be rejected.

Another app `telegram` is capable of removing messages read on another device - even this app does not have VOIP support.
So am I missing out somewhat or does `telegram` simply violates apple's guidelines?

regards

coyer

Comment: Have you checked the new Mutable Notifications in iOS 10?

Comment: Great stuff for iOS 10, I hoped there is something for iOS >= 8

Comment: In that case you should look up apns-collapse-id. UPDATE: It seems you're out of luck, iOS 10 and above. I'm sorry.

Comment: The standard approach is to use the push notification to display a local notification. Then she a message is read, send another push notification with that information. The app then cancels the local notification and it is removed. The stack exchange app does this for example

Comment: Thx for the replies. @Lior I just started digging into telegram's code (after I noticed it's OpenSource). As I am not familiar with ObjC I haven't any glue yet. In telegram there's only push-notifications set and remote notifications and even when the app is not launched they can delete notifications even on iOS 9 (and older devices?)

Comment: I assume that telegram will remove *all* notifications by simply setting `badge` to 0 for APNs (which will only work if previous messages had a badge > 0). So I will use iOS10 API, thx @Lior

Comment: Its possible I believe; [Check this SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289348/remotely-remove-previously-sent-notification/46154128#46154128).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I end up using VOIP-pushnotifications and create my own local notifications with `UNNotificationRequest`.
I then have the opportunity to remove my outdated notifications at any time.

Apple indeed asks why I am using VOIP-push but accepted the app after I states that there is no other way removing outdated notifications.