# Remotely remove previously sent notification

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, ios10

Since iOS 10 and `UNUserNotificationCenter`, a lot of things can be achieved with notifications, but I can't figure out how to remotely remove a push notification *every time*.

Using the `mutable-content` attribute, I'm able to modify the content of my push notification.
But let's say I want to remove it later (the content has expired). I used `content-available` and then the following code:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
                        .removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: [xxx])
```

It almost works, except (and that's a major problem) when the app was swiped out of memory by the user.

Has anyone found a way to remove notifications?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24006607/5546312) we have to send another push notification to clear previously sent notifications.

That notification should contain `badge:0`, and omit the `alert` and `sound` fields, then it will remove notifications from notification centre as well as clear app badge.